# NoSuchMethodError:com.android.app.fragment getContext in android

Tags: android

Am getting this error for php webservices in GridView category and category images are in  array list I have to display them in grid view thrpough web services But error has been occured in getData() as NoSuchMethodError 
please try to help me Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customerhomepage, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    ids = new ArrayList<>();
    categorys = new ArrayList<>();
    category_imgs = new ArrayList<>();

    //Calling the getData method
    getData();
    return rootView;
}

private void getData() {

    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Please wait...", "Fetching data...", false, false);

    //Creating a json array request to get the json from our api
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing the progressdialog on response
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Displaying our grid
                    showGrid(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );
```

Logcat Error:

```
    03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.app.a2aapp, PID: 23736
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.app.a2aapp.HomeFragment.getContext
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.app.a2aapp.HomeFragment.getData(HomeFragment.java:67)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.app.a2aapp.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:61)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5257)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-20 22:35:58.002 23736-23736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think you DATA_URL is wrong.

Comment: No I gave the URL named as DATA_URL

Comment: I understood that, if the url you gave did not exist in the sever you are trying to interact, you'll get that error..

Comment: But it is existing in server. Still it is working in browser I checked it

Comment: Please post the stack trace here so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: @Mounika Is the exception been thrown when creating the `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: @Mounika Change `getContext()` to `getActivity()`.

Comment: Yes I changed it but it is showing null

Comment: Post `onCreateView` from your Fragment. Did you call super() in `onCreateView`?

Comment: @Mounika `getActivity()` returns `null` inside the fragment?

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customerhomepage, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        ids = new ArrayList<>();
        categorys = new ArrayList<>();
        category_imgs = new ArrayList<>();

        //Calling the getData method
        getData();
        return rootView;
    }

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 17):

Method [getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getContext()) is available on API level 23.
Try to use [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()).

Comment: Target API version or on your device/emulator?

Comment: I used with getActivity() but am getting the same error.